# backbone.js views directly calling the print function

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js, backbone-views

I have a backbone view that has a click event on print button like this:

```
var updateInvoice=Backbone.View.extend({

 template:_.template(mytemplate),

 events:{'click #print':'print'},

 print:function()
 {
    window.frames['contentIframe'].print();
 }

 });
```

Now the problem is that whenever the above view is instantiated, the print function automatically gets called without waiting for the click event to happen.

Comment: You are missing a quote, so this isn't your real code. From what you posted it looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

try rename the function to a non-standar name, like:

```
var updateInvoice=Backbone.View.extend({

 template:._template(mytemplate),

 events:{'click #print':'printInvoice'},

 printInvoice:function()
 {
    window.frames['contentIframe'].print();
 }

});
```